# PLS-00103: Encountered the symbol "(" when expecting one of the following

Tags: sql, oracle

I am trying to create a table in Oracle DB and I am getting this error:

```
PLS-00103: Encountered the symbol "(" when expecting one of the following:
. , @ in <an identifier>
<a double-quoted delimited-identifier> partition subpartition
```

The create statement is the following:

```
set echo on 
set term on
set pause off
set pages 5000
set serveroutput on size 99999
spool sqlResult.lst

  
declare
 --
wcont number :=0;
    
begin


CREATE TABLE schema.TABLE 
       (ID NUMBER GENERATED BY DEFAULT AS IDENTITY,
       DOCUMENT1 VARCHAR2(50),
       DOCUMENT2 VARCHAR2(50),
       ID_CLIENT1 NUMBER,
       ID_CLIENT2 NUMBER,
       BDATEO DATE,
       FDATE DATE,
       ID_PROCESS VARCHAR2(100),
       TYPE VARCHAR2(50),
       CONSTRAINT tmp_pk PRIMARY KEY(ID));


wcont:=wcont+ sql%ROWCOUNT;

if  sql%ROWCOUNT > 1
  then
     RAISE_APPLICATION_ERROR(-20010,'ERROR');
  end if;
 --
  commit;
 --
  dbms_output.put_line('SUCCESS');
   --
  exception
       when others then
            rollback;
            dbms_output.put_line(sqlerrm);
end;
/
spool off
exit
```

I can't see where is the error because the only "(" are after new table name and I think it's mandatory.

Best regards!

Comment: You can't run DDL statements like `create table` as static SQL in a PL/SQL context. You would have to use dynamic SQL; but why are you using PL/SQL here at all? The commit and rollback (and rowcount) don't make sense for DDL.

Comment: @AlexPoole Thank for ur answer.. I am not really good in SQL so I taked and example from an UPDATE statement where I handle errors and I changed it to this CREATE statement. How can I handle errors in a DDL like this?

Comment: You aren't really handling errors here anyway. Just remove all the PL/SQL parts - everything from `declare` to `/`, except the actual `create` statement. If that errors that the message will be shown in the spool file anyway.